# Write a batch file to do call another batch file and install a program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having trouble with a batch file. I have 2 files the first batch file runs and it creates the directory and copies the files needed. It appears to call the second batch file correctly because it opens the instructions.txt but then it stops. I will be running the first batch file from a CD and then the dbinstall.bat from the C:\testing folder.

this is my setup.bat

```
    @echo off

    md "C:\testing"

    xcopy *.* C:\testing

    CALL "C:\testing\dbinstall.bat"
```

Which in turns should call and run this

```
    REM ***PLEASE REPLACE %DWVerFileName.exe WITH THE PROPER VERSION OF THE EXE FILE***
    REM ***MAKE SURE THE 7z FILE INCLUDES THE CUSTOMER NAME AND THEN CHANGE %filename%.7z TO THE FILE NAME***

    CALL "C:\testing\Instructions.rtf"

    start /b /wait "C:\testing\7z423.exe"

    SET AppExePath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe"
    IF NOT EXIST %AppExePath% SET AppExePath="%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe"
    %AppExePath% e database.7z

    start /b /wait "setup.exe"

    SQLCMD -E -S touch -Q "RESTORE DATABASE testing FROM DISK='C:\testing\database.bak'"
```

I am stuck and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What error you received in batch?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have no idea of what "it stops" means, or where "it stops", I'd guess

```
CALL "C:\testing\Instructions.rtf"
```

should be

```
start "instructions" "C:\testing\Instructions.rtf"
```

which would then invoke whatever program is associated with `.rtf`, no doubt dislaying the instructions and keeping the displaying mechanism open while the `7z423` executable runs.